# MS Teams Meeting integration in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to create an Application in C# which can be able to integrate with Microsoft Team, where I can schedule  teams meeting, get the meeting list and update, but while creating the MS Teams meeting I'm getting the below error.

'Code: BadRequest

Message: /me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.

Use the below code for creating MS teams meeting

```
string clientId = "";
string clientSecret = "";
string tenantId = "";
string redirectUri = ""; 

string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";

////string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";

// Create a confidential client application
var confidentialClientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
    .Build();

// Define the scopes required for Microsoft Graph API
////string[] scopes = { "User.Read", "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite" }; // Add any additional scopes needed
var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

try
{
    // Acquire an access token
    var result = await confidentialClientApp
        .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync();

    // Use the access token in your Graph API requests
    string accessToken = result.AccessToken;

    // Create a GraphServiceClient
    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    }));

    // Create an online meeting
    var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
    {
        StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5), // Schedule the meeting 5 minutes from now
        EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1), // Set the duration of the meeting (1 hour in this example)
        Subject = "Teams Meeting created via Graph API",
    };

    var createdMeeting = await graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(onlineMeeting);

    Console.WriteLine($"Meeting created with ID: {createdMeeting.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Join URL: {createdMeeting.JoinWebUrl}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring token or making Graph API request: {ex.Message}");
}
```

Comment: Based on the error message you're receiving, it seems like you're trying to use the /me endpoint with application permissions. The /me endpoint is designed to work with delegated permissions, meaning it operates within the context of the signed-in user.
To resolve this issue, you should use the /users/{id | userPrincipalName} endpoint instead of /me when you're using application permissions. This endpoint allows you to specify the user for whom you're creating the meeting.

Comment: To use application permission for this API, tenant administrators must create an [application access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) and grant it to a user to authorize the app configured in the policy to create online meetings on behalf of that user (with user ID specified in the request path).